# The different ways to load data in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I study the way to load data in Tensorflow with **tf.contrib.learn.datasets**

For example,

1. To load Iris data set, [Iris flower classifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn), they used the following code:

   ```
   training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
   filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
   target_dtype=np.int,
   features_dtype=np.float32)
   ```
2. To load mnist [MNIST](https://gist.github.com/dandelionmane/4f02ab8f1451e276fea1f165a20336f1#file-mnist-py), they used:

   ```
   mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.mnist.read_data_sets(train_dir=LOGDIR + 'data', one_hot=True)
   ```

Could you help me to figure out the different between two ways. In particular, how can we know which way can be suitable for given type of data?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that there is one way to load data in TF: it depends on the format of your data, ecc. You may want to take a look to [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data) explaining the mechanism and the *philosophy* behind the input pipelines.

Comment: @ petrux: thanks very much. It will be a ton of readings for my beginning

Comment: I add it as a side comment: I gave a small tutorial on TF at my workplace and prepared [this notebook](https://github.com/petrux/TF-102/blob/master/05-InputPipeline.ipynb) on input pipelines. HTH.